# Display preference fragments in a full view

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferencefragment

I am using a preference fragment and replacing the fragment in the `id` of the root layout of the main xml file. So my problem is that the preferences are displaying alongside with the main activity xml elements.

I have seen in Android apps that the preferences open up separately I am not sure whether they do open up separately or just occupying the entire screen. For opening the preference fragment I am doing a normal fragment transaction(Note: I am not using the support library not sure if this has something to do with my problem but still mentioning it).

Here is what the problem is,
[image]

And so here is my code

**sampleprefs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:title="Check box preference"
        android:key="check_box_preference_1" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="Default value"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="Edit text preference"
        android:key="edit_text_preference_1" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is the main layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.random.preferenceexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Main Activity code where the fragment displays on the click of a button,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    boolean result;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        SettingsFragment sf = new SettingsFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.activity_main,sf);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

This is the fragment class

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.sampleprefs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the problem seems to be with the background transparency of `Fragment`. `Fragments` are transparent backgrounded by default because they can be used to paint only a small portion of the screen but if you want your `Fragment` to cover fullscreen then just add some background to it, it will work.

Moreover, it's good practice to use a root layout which supports views to be placed one above the other(for ex. FrameLayout) for `FragmentTransactions`.

Answer (score 1):

Add these in your Fragment :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        return view;
    }
```

[Here is the working example](https://github.com/TasneemBohra/PreferenceFragmentDemo)